# Soap UI DB custom authentication

Tags: soapui

I am trying to figure out how to extend Soap UI to enable DB authentication to use custom encryption/decryption classes for DB connections and should be able to read encrypted passwords. Please guide me where can find the extension interfaces or if there is any other approach.
thanks,
Josh